# BIOS screen freeze after clean install Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, freeze

I just upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10 and now my BIOS screen freezes everytime I try to start. I am using the AsRock P67 Pro3 motherboard. When I shut the computer off and turn it back on again it comes from "hibernation" and doesnt go throught the BIOS screen.

The computer is still accessible I just hit F6 for instant flash and then press the esc key. All the other stuff is working fine.

In order to install windows 10 i had to manually change my disk from MBR to GPT. Can somebody please help me solve this problem?